# CSS Border does not wrap around floated items

Tags: css

I am trying to create a two column layout. Left column is the nav menu, right column is content.

The problem is, the border wrapping all of the content wraps only the right column content, while the left column nav menu visually runs off of the div border.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ekeWz/

Is it possible to get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey now give to the **#wrapper** `overflow:hidden;` in your css as like this

```
#wrapper {
overflow:hidden;}
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ekeWz/1/)

Comment: It's not a case of Collapsing Margin. In this case if there is an float in the Child DIV's then you have to clear it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your desired result through give the `overflow:hidden;` to your parent div or `#wrapper` div

http://jsfiddle.net/ekeWz/6/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;}
#left_menu {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;}
    width: 25%;}
```

once you break the flow of the div with the float left in the left_menu, you have to adjust the flow of the parent div with the same float.